# Python read COM and instert into PostgresSQL

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

Im having an issue trying to post variables into PostgresSQL via python. My code is below

```
import serial
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
   database="dfa", user='postgres', password='blankedout', host='192.168.1.88', port= '5432'
)
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()

serialPort = serial.Serial(
    port="COM10", baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
)

while 1:
    if serialPort.in_waiting > 0:
        serialString = ""
        serialString = serialPort.readline()
        text = serialString.decode("Ascii")
        print("COM output is:")
        print(text)
        try:
            a,b,c,d = text.split(',')
            #test = ((float(a),)), (float(b),), (float(c),))
            test = ((float(1),), (float(b),), (float(40),))
            print("Test output is:")            
            print(test)
            print(type(test))
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO datalog(name, temp, humidity, time) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,NOW())", test)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        except:
            pass
```

I have hashed out a line that I want where is inputs all values from a,b and c but it just does not work.

`#test = ((float(a),)), (float(b),), (float(c),))`
The test variable below does work if I make a single variable (example b).

`test = ((float(1),), (float(b),), (float(40),))`
print functions are for debug.

text (COM output)
`COM output is: 1,24.10,45.10,NOW()`

test output and type is:
`Test output is: ((1.0,), (24.1,), (40.0,))`

Would like to put the a,b,c variables into SQL like below

```
test = ((float(a),)), (float(b),), (float(c),))
.
.
.
.
.
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO datalog(name, temp, humidity, time) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,NOW())", test)
```

Comment: 1) Define *...does not work*. Provide exact traceback as text update to question text. 2) Why not `...(%s::float,%s::float,%s::float,NOW()), [a, b, c ]`?

Comment: This `((float(a),)), (float(b),), (float(c),))` should be `(float(a), float(b), float(c))` per [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).